# PyQt: Async console output not captured with every application

Tags: python, asynchronous, console, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to start the Arduino IDE in command line mode and get the standard output back into my PyQt application like this:

```
def recvConsoleOutput(self, output):
    print(output)

def upload(self):
    [...]
    cmd = [ARDUINO_PATH,
           '--verbose',
           '--upload', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sketch', 'sketch.ino'),
           '--port', self.serialPort.currentText(),
           '--board', 'arduino:avr:leonardo']
    cmd = ' '.join(cmd)

    proc = AsyncProcess(cmd, self.recvConsoleOutput, parent=self)
    proc.start()
```

It is called within a QMainWindow function and works flawlessly (Arduino IDE uploads the sketch!) except the fact, that it does not output any messages like it does when called by the regular windows command prompt.

The AsyncProcess class looks like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt5.Qt import QProcess


class AsyncProcess(QObject):
    def __init__(self, path, slot, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.path = path
        self.proc = None
        self.slot = slot

    def start(self):
        self.proc = QProcess(self)
        self.proc.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.readStandardOutput)
        self.proc.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.readStandardError)
        self.proc.start(self.path)

    def readStandardOutput(self):
        procOutput = self.proc.readAllStandardOutput()
        self.slot(procOutput)

    def readStandardError(self):
        procOutput = self.proc.readAllStandardError()
        self.slot(procOutput)
```

It works for some reason if I start "ping 127.0.0.1" instead of Arduino.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, mea culpa. At some point the developers of the IDE decided to output the information I needed only in the designated debugging version... I was actually calling the wrong executable...